# Can't fire this jQuery in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use this jQuery `$projectWrapper.find('#test').html($("figure[style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 700px; z-index: 5; height: auto; cursor: pointer;'] img").attr('src'));`

Inside this AJAX function that's used in a slider.

Basically each time there's a click to navigate pre or next I need to update or re fire my jQuery above so that the #test html is updated. I tried placing my jQuery as you'll see below the `var $navLinksDiv` but it's not firing at all. How can I re-write this function so my jquery fires on each click and update the #test ID's html?

Thanks

```
function eQsliderNavInit() {

    var $navLinksDiv = $( '#slides #next-prev-links img' );
    $projectWrapper.find('#test').html($("figure[style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 700px; z-index: 5; height: auto; cursor: pointer;'] img").attr('src'));
    var sliderHoverOverFunction = function() {
        if ( !$( 'body' ).hasClass('ie8') ) {
            $navLinksDiv.stop().animate( { opacity: 0.5 }, 200, 'easeInOutExpo' );
        }
        else {
            $navLinksDiv.css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    } 

    var sliderHoverOutFunction = function() {
        if ( !$( 'body' ).hasClass('ie8') ) {
            $navLinksDiv.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 450, 'easeInOutCubic');         
        }
        else {
            $navLinksDiv.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }   
    } 

    $( '.slider' ).hover( sliderHoverOverFunction, sliderHoverOutFunction );

}
```

Comment: Your selectors are to specific, ID's are unique, there's no need to use two of them, and that style selector seems awfully hard to match. One space missing and you're screwed. As to the real question, where's the ajax at ?

Comment: totally agree with @adeneo, surely you can add an ID or class to the `figure` tag to make selector a lot more accurate ( and easier to read)

Comment: @adeneo the selector works fine and searches a few tags with inline styles and selects the image in the slide that's currently displayed.

Comment: @adeneo this is the ajax http://pastebin.com/aTj6Ye9f I also have commented out my jquery which is working when the page loads but doesn't refire when I click the image, prev, or next buttons to slide to the next image. So basically I need that jquery to refire some how on clicking pre/next

Comment: _"the selector works fine"_ - Yes, but adeneo's point is still valid. The only reason you'd ever include two ids inside a selector like that is if you want to match the second element only if it exists as a descendant of the first.